# How to load a type behavior from an XML?

Tags: clojure

I'm learning Clojure through building a simple game. I have this protocol and a type that implements it:

```
(defprotocol Event
  (event [this]))

(deftype Card [name]
  Event
  (event [this]
    (println "Do event")))
```

But I would like to not define the behavior of `event` function but instead load this behavior from an XML file later and assign it at runtime on `Card` type instantiation. Is this possible? How to do it in Clojure?

Comment: Of _course_ it is possible! Duh!

Comment: @DonalFellows: He's asking for a code example.  I've voted to close/migrate to Stack Overflow.

Comment: @DonalFellows *How to do it in Clojure?*

Comment: @RobertHarvey If I knew how to write it in Clojure, I'd have answered properly…

Comment: @m0skit0 Have a look at http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/eval but it could be too dangerous!

Comment: @Chiron I know about `eval` but I can't figure out how to do it at runtime. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it loading the behavior from the file with `load-string` and calling it from `event`, so I only need one `deftype` for all the cards:

```
(deftype Card [name event-function]
  Event
  (event [this] event-function))
```

So now if I do

```
(def card (Card. "Default card" (load-string "#(println %) \"Event called\"")))
(.event card)
```

it will print

```
Event called
```

Loading this string from an XML is trivial with `clojure.xml/parse`. For example:

```
(clojure.xml/parse (.getResourceAsStream (class Object) "/cards.xml"))
```

Which will return the XML as a map.

Answer (score -1):

You should gen-class or create it on Java
http://code.google.com/p/clojure/issues/detail?id=45

Comment: Thanks but not really an answer. How do I load the type behavior? How do I assign it to a type at runtime?

Comment: But, Clojure is not OO, even if it's possible to tweak... make it idiomatically...

Comment: Sorry I don't understand, what has OOP to do with my question? How to make it idiomatically? Can you provide a simple example?